# Java JNA: call DLL, run it several times, and then error "Invalid memory access"

Tags: jna

The DLL is created by Java, calling Delphi through JNA, and can be run several times before an error will be reported. Is it because of the wrong type, or because there is a problem with the internal memory of the DLL or something?

Java signature:

```java
public interface DLL extends Library {

    DLL CCAWDll = Native.load("invoke", DLL.class);

    String invoke(String fileName, float a, float b, float c, float d,
                 float e, float f, float g, float h, float i,
                 float j, String k);

}
```

Delphi signature:

```pascal
function invoke(filename: PAnsiChar; a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j: single; k: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar; stdcall;
```

Error stack:

> ```
> ===================================9th time, call DLL===================================
> ===================================10th time, call DLLL===================================
> 2023-03-10 10:25:56.417 ERROR 12592 --- [-nio-94-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : > Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access] with root cause
>
> java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
>   at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:497) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:660) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:434) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265) ~[jna-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0 (b0)]
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>   at com.xxx.xxx.dll.impl.DllImpl.invoke(DllImpl.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
>   at com.xxx.xxx.dll.impl.DllImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92dce636.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
>   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
>   at com.xxx.xxx.dll.impl.DllImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c67e343.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
> ```

No exception was found from the memory in the JVM and no overflow was seen. I don't know if there is a problem with the data I checked.

Method call:

```java
public  class DllImpl extends DllManage implements DllProvider {

    public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    @Override
    public synchronized ResponseEntity<String> invoke(String fileName, float a, float b,
                                                      float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h, float i, float j, String k) {
        System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "GBK");
        count.getAndIncrement();
        String result = null;
        System.out.println("==================================="+count+"th time, call DLL===================================");
        try {
            result = DLL.CCAWDll.invoke(fileName,
                    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,
                    k);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.gc();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Delphi Specific code:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(t2); // Get end count value
r1 := (t2 - t1) / c1; // Get the timing time in seconds (s)
r2 := (t2 - t1) / c1 * 1000; // Get the timing time in milliseconds (ms)
r3 := (t2 - t1) / c1 * 1000000; // Get the timing time in microseconds
WritelnTxt('fileName:' + filename);
WritelnTxt('Time of calling CCAWDll:' + FloatToStr(r2));
//TJsonSerializer class, more efficient and faster
serial := TJsonSerializer.Create;
S := serial.Serialize<INSOLUTION>(returnDetail); // [{"name": "Zhang Zhang", "age": 1}, {"name": "Wang Wang", "age": 2}]
QueryPerformanceCounter(t3); // Get end count value
r4 := (t3 - t2) / c1 * 1000; // Get timing time
WritelnTxt('Generate json time:' + FloatToStr(r4));
//write file
WritelnTxtFile(S);
//return 
GetMem(PStr, Length(S) + 1); // This 1 is used to store the 0 string terminator
StrPCopy(PStr, S);
Result := PAnsiChar(PStr);
```

returnDetail is the return data. I convert it to json and send it to java.

If I write directly to the file, no error will be reported. If I convert it to PansiCHar and return it to java, an error will be reported after multiple calls.

Comment: First, need more details on your code.  Where is the `invoke()` method called?  If it's a callback, check if it's being GC'd and becoming unreachable.

Comment: If I can call it normally, I can confirm that my data type is correct, and the number of calls will not affect it, right？

Comment: JAVA called dll, no callback code. However, the code in the dll calls other dll link libraries

Comment: You still need to post the code where you're calling `invoke()`.  The stack trace is not helpful without whatever `at com.xxx.xxx.dll.impl.DllImpl.invoke(DllImpl.java:40) ~[classes/:na]` points to.

Comment: DllImpl calls the method defined in the class file of the dll,
"at com.xxx.xxx.dll.impl.DllImpl.invoke(DllImpl.java:40) "  Is the place in  try{}  catch{}. Because there are some println in the middle, I removed them, so the line number is a bit incorrect.

Comment: Please do not mistake comments as chat messages - rather include new details into your question. Also: have you spotted the "Related" pane on the left side, linking to existing questions with nearly the same title? Although being a member of 4+ years you should consider using the [tour] at least once and learn to properly use formattings in both post and comments.

Comment: Note the Delphi signature includes `stdcall;`. Try extending `StdCallLibrary` rather than `Library`.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thank you for your reminder. I will check the specific format.So do you have any suggestions for this problem？

Comment: @Daniel Widdis 
CLibrary、StdCallLibrary extends Library.
CLibrary supports * nix-based operating systems, such as various Unix branches and Linux.
StdCallLibrary supports the Windows operating system.

If the wrong Library base class is inherited during use, the unrecognized calling convention error will be reported. So the suggestions are inherited from Library. So I think the impact is not big, and I just did the test and got the same results.

Comment: delphi  PStr ：GetMem(PStr, Length(S) + 1);   

The applied memory has not been released. The new code:
  if(PStr <> nil) then FreeMem(PStr);
  PStr := GetMemory(Length(S) + 1);

PStr Use global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delphi:--> PStr ：

```
GetMem(PStr, Length(S) + 1);
```

The applied memory has not been released. The new code:
PStr Use global variables.

```
if(PStr <> nil) then FreeMem(PStr);
PStr := GetMemory(Length(S) + 1);
```